# Non-space space

Tags: regex, cocoa, expression, match

This seems rather odd to me, but here is my problem:
I want to strip all spaces down to one space. When I try the regex

```
[ ]{2,}
```

it should match correctly. In my data I unfortunately seem to have some "non-space spaces":

```
Hallo,     was genau
```

(I don't know if the characters are correctly copied into stackoverflow)

When I try out my regex in Sublime Text I get two matches between "Hallo," and "was", leaving one character in the middle right between them. Additionally if I try

```
[^A-Za-z,]{2,}
```

the whitespaces are matched like I want.

What is going on here and how can I correctly match the spaces?

Comment: When I copy the "data" back from so I don't have the problem. Just as a hint

Comment: It's worth finding out what your "non-space space" characters are.  If this data is read from a file, look at it in a hex viewer.  Or alternatively, just loop through the characters and print out their numeric values.

Comment: Do you want to use this eventually in Sublime Text or some other environment?

Comment: I want to use this with Cocoa, I am now looping through the characters. Good point ;-)

Comment: Try to use `[\8-\20]{2,}`.

Comment: python says:    `>>> for i in 'Hallo,     ':
...     print(ord(i))
...
72
97
108
108
111
44
32
32
160
32
32`

Comment: I found this: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/338821-trim-function-doesnt-clean-out-ascii-code-160-space.html

Comment: It's called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space .. I am now on my way to find out how exactly match it with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NSRegularExpression

```
\u00a0
```

matches the so-called **non-breaking space** (ascii code 160).

I used

```
[ \u00a0]{2,}
```

to match ALL spaces.